# JUnit or JMeter for a WebApp user creation and Login using session cookies test scenario?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmeter, integration-testing

I would like to ask which would be the best tool to test 1. (multiple) user creations and 2. login using session cookies in a WebApp?

Do both JUnit and JMeter support such testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JUnit is an [XUnit testing framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit), it supports everything you write in Java, however you will need to implement the logic, concurrency, results analysis, etc. yourself, JUnit only provides API to configure and run tests and to define pass/fail criteria
2. [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) is a multi-protocol load testing tool, concurrency, metrics and results you have out of the box, for web applications load testing you have [HTTP Reques](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)t sampler and the cookies are automatically handled using [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) (it's possible to add cookies manually as well)

So if you need to setup everything quickly JMeter should fit your needs as writing a browser-like HTTP client will take immense effort and time.

More information:

- [Building a Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)